# AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'OrderedDict' when I try to download dbt dependencies

Tags: python, typing, dbt

I am getting the `AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'OrderedDict'` error when I try to download dependencies. I have upgraded to python 3.7.1 but still getting the error. I have this typing module in my list of packages: `typing-extensions==3.7.4.3` I have no idea what else could it be. It gives me the error in source code where there is `typing.OrderDict` being called.

Comment: What version of dbt are you using?

Comment: I have the same issue, I used dbt: 0.21.1

Comment: Opened issue https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/4564

Comment: Same here - just upgraded dbt.

Answer (score 1):

I've upgraded my python to `3.6.3` from `3.6.0` and it's working